# WMS routine gives error

Tags: wms, openlayers

I am having this error message from ol3-wms(-Geoserver) routine:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closure_uid_477334679' of undefined ol.js:17`
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hf' of undefined ol.js:180`

Here is the related code:

```
wms_depivmLayer = new ol.layer.Image({  
   extent : [ 2857613.741389, 4274927.875099 , 4989786.191152 , 5176940.449967],
   source : new ol.source.ImageWMS({
       url: 'http://localhost:8181/geoserver/work1/wms',
       params: { 'LAYERS' : 'work1:depiv3_3857' },
       serverType : 'geoserver',
       format :'image/GeoTiff'
   })
})
map.addLayer(wms_depivmLayer);
```

I tried `new ol.source.TileWMS({...`, but it fails.

Bur when I use curl :

`curl --trace -i -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/image" http://localhost:8181/geoserver/work1/wms?service=WMS&version=1.0.0&request=GetMap&layers=work1:depiv3_3857&styles=&bbox=2857613.741389,4274927.875099,4989786.191152,5176940.449967&width=780&height=330&srs=EPSG:3857&format=image/GeoTiff" > out.png`

it is OK.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it work with format image/png ?

Answer (score 1):

try calling it with `ol.layer.Tile()` instead like this:

```
var yourLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    extent: [2857613.741389, 4274927.875099 , 4989786.191152 , 5176940.449967],
    visible: true,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
       url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms',
       params: {
           'LAYERS': 'yourWorkspace:yourLayer',
           'TILED': true,
           'FORMAT': 'image/png', 
           'CRS': 'EPSG:3857'
       },
       serverType: 'geoserver'
       }))
   });
   map.addLayer(yourLayer);
```